# Server Management - Need script to monitor free space on server

Tags: windows, powershell

**Need script to monitor free space on server** and if the free memory space goes done certain threshold **send alert mail.**

**PS**- I think the solution will be Power Shell + Windows Timer Job. I am new to Power Shell though.

Comment: thank you all for the replies, i was able to implement the scheduled timer job on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get free disk space using a command like this:

```
([wmi]"\\$computer\root\cimv2:Win32_logicalDisk.DeviceID='$drive'").FreeSpace
```

And you cand send an email using the function below:

```
function Send-EMail 
{ 
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $EmailTo = "<Your destination email>",
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $EmailFrom = "<The sending email address>",
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $EmailSubject = "Disk space problem",
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $SMTPServer = "<your smtp server>"
    )

    $MailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage  
    $MailMessage.From = ($EmailFrom)  
    $MailMessage.To.Add($EmailTo) 
    $MailMessage.Subject = $EmailSubject 
    $MailMessage.Body = $EmailBody 
    $MailMessage.IsBodyHTML = $true 

    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)   
    $SMTPClient.Send($MailMessage) 
}
```

Now combine these two functions in a PowerShell script that you can [schedule with Windows scheduller](http://www.searchmarked.com/windows/how-to-schedule-a-windows-powershell-script.php).

Answer (score 3):

You need to deal with WMI objects.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315295.aspx

Scripting might not be necessary. If you are on Wk3 Server you can enable quota management on volumes. W2k8 has extended quota management to volume folders also.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733029.aspx