# How to get disk capacity and free space of remote computer

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I have this one-liner:

```
get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername remotecomputer
```

and the output is this:

```
DeviceID     : A:
DriveType    : 2
ProviderName :
FreeSpace    :
Size         :
VolumeName   :

DeviceID     : C:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName :
FreeSpace    : 20116508672
Size         : 42842714112
VolumeName   :

DeviceID     : D:
DriveType    : 5
ProviderName :
FreeSpace    :
Size         :
VolumeName   :
```

How do I get `Freespace` and `Size` of `DeviceID` `C:`? I need to extract just these two values with no other informations. I have tried it with `Select` cmdlet, but with no effect.

**Edit:** 
I need to extract the numerical values only and store them in variables.

Comment: PS C:\> icm remotecomputer {gdr C | select Free,@{Name='Size'; Expression={$_.Free+$_.Used}}}

Comment: None of these answers worked out, as i am behind a firewall and in corporate network, any other options ?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

```
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName remotecomputer -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" |
Select-Object Size,FreeSpace

$disk.Size
$disk.FreeSpace
```

To extract the values only and assign them to a variable:

```
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName remotecomputer -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" |
Foreach-Object {$_.Size,$_.FreeSpace}
```

Comment: simply adding $disk.Size / 1GB makes the result more readable also.

Comment: If you want to round the display to only show whole numbers, use `[Math]::Round($Disk.Freespace / 1GB)`

Comment: in powershell why does `1mb` return a value of `1048576` and not `1000000` ????

Comment: @oldboy because it uses powers of 2: 2^20 vs. 10^6. It should indeed be written `1MiB` (with proper case) but is usually shown in lower case, without th "i". See [Mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

Comment: @oldboy why mb, this time is long over, we are 000 further regarding memory.

Comment: I get an error "Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable."

Answer (score 170):

Much simpler solution:

```
Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object Used,Free
```

and for remote computers (needs `Powershell Remoting`)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SRV2 {Get-PSDrive C} | Select-Object PSComputerName,Used,Free
```

Comment: Install [PSTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/ko-kr/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and do
`psexec -u administrator \\[computer name or IP] powershell "get-psdrive C"`

Comment: If you need to authenticate, this will require "Kerberos authentication mechanism" enabled in the remote machine.

Comment: If you want this more readable try: 'Get-PSDrive | Select-Object @{Expression={$_.Free/1TB}}'

Comment: In many corporate environments, PowerShell Remoting may not be available.

Comment: Any way to overcome @brianary statement ?

Comment: How do I put commas in the space available value

Answer (score 75):

Just one command simple sweet and clean but this only works for local disks

```
Get-PSDrive
```

[image]

You could still use this command on a remote server by doing a Enter-PSSession -Computername ServerName  and then run the Get-PSDrive it will pull the data as if you ran it from the server.

Comment: To get only filesystem drives: `Get-PSDrive | ? { $_.Provider.Name -eq 'FileSystem' }`

Comment: Is there any way to give this command with authentication credentials ? Say for example
Enter-PSSession -Computername 10.167.162.61 --user --password ?

Answer (score 19):

I created a PowerShell advanced function (script cmdlet) a while back that allows you to query multiple computers.

The code for the function is a little over 100 lines long, so you can find it here: [PowerShell version of the df command](http://binarynature.blogspot.com/2010/04/powershell-version-of-df-command.html)

Check out the **Usage** section for examples. The following usage example queries a set of remote computers (input from the PowerShell pipeline) and displays the output in a table format with numeric values in human-readable form:

```
PS> $cred = Get-Credential -Credential 'example\administrator'
PS> 'db01','dc01','sp01' | Get-DiskFree -Credential $cred -Format | Format-Table -GroupBy Name -AutoSize

   Name: DB01

Name Vol Size  Used  Avail Use% FS   Type
---- --- ----  ----  ----- ---- --   ----
DB01 C:  39.9G 15.6G 24.3G   39 NTFS Local Fixed Disk
DB01 D:  4.1G  4.1G  0B     100 CDFS CD-ROM Disc


   Name: DC01

Name Vol Size  Used  Avail Use% FS   Type
---- --- ----  ----  ----- ---- --   ----
DC01 C:  39.9G 16.9G 23G     42 NTFS Local Fixed Disk
DC01 D:  3.3G  3.3G  0B     100 CDFS CD-ROM Disc
DC01 Z:  59.7G 16.3G 43.4G   27 NTFS Network Connection


   Name: SP01

Name Vol Size   Used   Avail Use% FS   Type
---- --- ----   ----   ----- ---- --   ----
SP01 C:  39.9G  20G    19.9G   50 NTFS Local Fixed Disk
SP01 D:  722.8M 722.8M 0B     100 UDF  CD-ROM Disc
```

Comment: I would like to use this function, but the blogspot domain is blocked for me. Could you please include the function here?

Comment: the same link on web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150614115736/http://binarynature.blogspot.ro/2010/04/powershell-version-of-df-command.html

Comment: Get-DiskFree does not appear to be available in PowerShell 2.0

Comment: Please don't post link to code, but code itself.

Comment: @Matthieu as long as the link is valid, there are advantages in doing so i.e. whenever you update the code there, everybody gets the new version.

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli of course, but at least explain what the code does and how it works. I've seen way too many answers giving a link that ultimately died, rendering the whole answer useless.

Comment: @Matthieu Yeah, you're right, I have seen that too, quite too often really

Answer (score 13):

There are two issues I encountered with the other suggestions

  **1)**
  Drive mappings are not supported if you run the powershell under task scheduler

  **2)**
  You may get
  **Access is denied**
  errors errors trying to used "get-WmiObject" on remote computers (depending on your infrastructure setup, of course)

The alternative that doesn't suffer from these issues is to use **GetDiskFreeSpaceEx** with a UNC path:

```
function getDiskSpaceInfoUNC($p_UNCpath, $p_unit = 1tb, $p_format = '{0:N1}')
{
    # unit, one of --> 1kb, 1mb, 1gb, 1tb, 1pb
    $l_typeDefinition = @' 
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] 
        public static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName, 
            out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable, 
            out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes, 
            out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes); 
'@
    $l_type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $l_typeDefinition -Name Win32Utils -Namespace GetDiskFreeSpaceEx -PassThru

    $freeBytesAvailable     = New-Object System.UInt64 # differs from totalNumberOfFreeBytes when per-user disk quotas are in place
    $totalNumberOfBytes     = New-Object System.UInt64
    $totalNumberOfFreeBytes = New-Object System.UInt64

    $l_result = $l_type::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx($p_UNCpath,([ref]$freeBytesAvailable),([ref]$totalNumberOfBytes),([ref]$totalNumberOfFreeBytes)) 

    $totalBytes     = if($l_result) { $totalNumberOfBytes    /$p_unit } else { '' }
    $totalFreeBytes = if($l_result) { $totalNumberOfFreeBytes/$p_unit } else { '' }

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Success   = $l_result
        Path      = $p_UNCpath
        Total     = $p_format -f $totalBytes
        Free      = $p_format -f $totalFreeBytes
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution but do we have similar function to get UNCpath for the all the user

Comment: Does the PowerShell method for mapped drives when not used by TaskScheduler?

Answer (score 11):

Another way is casting a string to a WMI object:

```
$size = ([wmi]"\\remotecomputer\root\cimv2:Win32_logicalDisk.DeviceID='c:'").Size
$free = ([wmi]"\\remotecomputer\root\cimv2:Win32_logicalDisk.DeviceID='c:'").FreeSpace
```

Also you can divide the results by 1GB or 1MB if you want different units:

```
$disk = ([wmi]"\\remotecomputer\root\cimv2:Win32_logicalDisk.DeviceID='c:'")
"Remotecomputer C: has {0:#.0} GB free of {1:#.0} GB Total" -f ($disk.FreeSpace/1GB),($disk.Size/1GB) | write-output
```

Output is: `Remotecomputer C: has 252.7 GB free of 298.0 GB Total`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026687/server-management-need-script-to-monitor-free-space-on-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715/best-way-to-query-disk-space-on-remote-server

Comment: @BillGreer Don't know offhand but I've often found WMI calls slower than PS. You can yourself test with Measure-Command but make sure to run it a bunch of times and average the results.

Answer (score 8):

```
Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object @{ E={$_.Used/1GB}; L='Used' }, @{ E={$_.Free/1GB}; L='Free' }
```

Answer (score 8):

Just found [Get-Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume?view=win10-ps) command, which returns `SizeRemaining`, so something like `(Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).SizeRemaining / (1e+9)` can be used to see remained Gb for disk C. Seems works faster than `Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk`.

Answer (score 7):

Command-line:

```
powershell gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName remotecomputer -Filter "DriveType=3" ^|
select Name, FileSystem,FreeSpace,BlockSize,Size ^| % {$_.BlockSize=
(($_.FreeSpace)/($_.Size))*100;$_.FreeSpace=($_.FreeSpace/1GB);$_.Size=($_.Size/1GB);$_}
^| Format-Table Name, @{n='FS';e={$_.FileSystem}},@{n='Free, Gb';e={'{0:N2}'-f
$_.FreeSpace}}, @{n='Free,%';e={'{0:N2}'-f $_.BlockSize}},@{n='Capacity ,Gb';e={'{0:N3}'
-f $_.Size}} -AutoSize
```

Output:

```
Name FS   Free, Gb Free,% Capacity ,Gb

---- --   -------- ------ ------------

C:   NTFS 16,64    3,57   465,752

D:   NTFS 43,63    9,37   465,759

I:   NTFS 437,59   94,02  465,418

N:   NTFS 5,59     0,40   1 397,263

O:   NTFS 8,55     0,96   886,453

P:   NTFS 5,72     0,59   976,562
```

command-line:

```
wmic logicaldisk where DriveType="3" get caption, VolumeName, VolumeSerialNumber, Size, FileSystem, FreeSpace
```

out:

```
Caption  FileSystem  FreeSpace     Size           VolumeName  VolumeSerialNumber

C:       NTFS        17864343552   500096991232   S01         EC641C36

D:       NTFS        46842589184   500104687616   VM1         CAF2C258

I:       NTFS        469853536256  499738734592   V8          6267CDCC

N:       NTFS        5998840832    1500299264512  Vm-1500     003169D1

O:       NTFS        9182349312    951821143552   DT01        A8FC194C

P:       NTFS        6147043840    1048575144448  DT02        B80A0F40
```

command-line:

```
wmic logicaldisk where Caption="C:" get caption, VolumeName, VolumeSerialNumber, Size, FileSystem, FreeSpace
```

out:

```
Caption  FileSystem  FreeSpace    Size          VolumeName  VolumeSerialNumber

C:       NTFS        17864327168  500096991232  S01         EC641C36

command-line:

dir C:\ /A:DS | find "free"

out:
               4 Dir(s)  17 864 318 976 bytes free

dir C:\ /A:DS /-C | find "free"

out:
               4 Dir(s)     17864318976 bytes free
```

Comment: This is ridiculous.

Comment: why @AlexanderTrauzzi?

Comment: `wmic logicaldisk get size` doesnt account for reserved space tho... in powershell `get-volume` returns the practical total size (i.e. minus reserved space), but then when i try `get-volume | format-list size` it says the total size plus the reserved space... how do i get the total size minus reserved space for each drive with powershell???

Answer (score 3):

```
PS> Get-CimInstance -ComputerName bobPC win32_logicaldisk | where caption -eq "C:" | foreach-object {write " $($_.caption) $('{0:N2}' -f ($_.Size/1gb)) GB total, $('{0:N2}' -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)) GB free "}  
C: 117.99 GB total, 16.72 GB free 

PS>
```

Comment: Nathan, I rolled back your edit. This shows the output given, which is valuable to those selecting an answer for its results. It's one line to copy & paste.

Answer (score 3):

On PowerShell:

```
"FreeSpace C:  " + [math]::Round((Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).SizeRemaining / 1Gb) + " GB"
```

Comment: Nice because it passes filters down to source.  I prefer efficiency (and simplicity, use built-in filter).

Answer (score 2):

I know of psExec tools which you can download from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx)

There comes a psinfo.exe from the tools package. The basic usage is in the following manner in powershell/cmd.

[image]

However you could have a lot of options with it

Usage: psinfo [[\computer[,computer[,..]  |  @file  [-u user
[-p psswd]]]   [-h]  [-s]  [-d]  [-c  [-t delimiter]] [filter]

\computer  Perform the command on the remote computer or computers specified. If you omit the computer name the command runs on the local system, and if you specify a wildcard (\*), the command runs on all computers in the current domain.

```
@file   Run the command on each computer listed in the text file specified.
-u  Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.
-p  Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
-h  Show list of installed hotfixes.
-s  Show list of installed applications.
-d  Show disk volume information.
-c  Print in CSV format.
-t  The default delimiter for the -c option is a comma, but can be overriden with the specified character.
```

filter  Psinfo will only show data for the field matching the filter. e.g. "psinfo service" lists only the service pack field.

Answer (score 0):

I remote into the computer using **Enter-PSsession pcName**
then I type **Get-PSDrive**

That will list all drives and space used and remaining. If you need to see all the info formated, pipe it to FL like this: **Get-PSdrive | FL ***

Answer (score 0):

I created this simple function to help me. This makes my calls a lot easier to read that having inline an [Get-WmiObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx), [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) statements, etc.

```
function GetDiskSizeInfo($drive) {
    $diskReport = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk
    $drive = $diskReport | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq $drive}

    $result = @{
        Size = $drive.Size
        FreeSpace = $drive.Freespace
    }
    return $result
}

$diskspace = GetDiskSizeInfo "C:"
write-host $diskspace.FreeSpace " " $diskspace.Size
```

Comment: OP was "Remote Computer". This didn't work for me on mounted drive, but that was probably on my end...

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to check multiple drive letters and/or filter between local and network drives, you can use PowerShell to take advantage of the [Win32_LogicalDisk WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) class. Here's a quick example:

```
$localVolumes = Get-WMIObject win32_volume;

foreach ($vol in $localVolumes) {
  if ($vol.DriveLetter -ne $null ) {
    $d = $vol.DriveLetter[0];
    if ($vol.DriveType -eq 3) {
      Write-Host ("Drive " + $d + " is a Local Drive");
    }
    elseif ($vol.DriveType -eq 4) {
      Write-Host ("Drive" + $d + " is a Network Drive");
    }
    else {
      // ... and so on
    }

    $drive = Get-PSDrive $d;
    Write-Host ("Used space on drive " + $d + ": " + $drive.Used + " bytes. `r`n");
    Write-Host ("Free space on drive " + $d + ": " + $drive.Free + " bytes. `r`n");
  }
}
```

I used the above technique to create a Powershell script that checks all drives and send an e-mail alert whenever they go below a user-defined quota. You can get it from [this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/runninglow-free-powershell-script-check-low-disk-space-send-email-alert/) on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell Fun

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername <ServerName> -Credential $(get-credential) | Select DeviceID,VolumeName,FreeSpace,Size | where {$_.DeviceID -eq "C:"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"FreeSpace C: {0:n3} GB" -f ((Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).SizeRemaining / 1Gb)`

Comment: @lynx_74 answer but format instead of calling `[Math]::Round()`, .NET built-in format string `n3`, or like `{0:0.000}`.  `{0:n0}` would round like lynx, but I prefer seeing more precision.

Comment: `-f` is "format operator" in PowerShell