# Docker on Windows Nano Server: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: azure, docker, windows-server-2016, nano-server, docker-for-windows

I'm sucessfully started docker on Windows Server 2016 Nano Server.
I've pulled images microsoft/nanoserver and microsoft/sample-dotnet

But when I tried to pull another images, like microsoft/dotnet-framework I've got the following message:

"docker : write C:\Windows\TEMP\GetImageBlob193586394: There is not enough space on the disk."

I'm using the Nano Server on Azure with a 512 GB SSD. And I've just deployed the OS.

Anyone knows what is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the disc size as viewed by Windows? Here's how to find it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159341/how-to-get-disk-capacity-and-free-space-of-remote-computer

Comment: Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object Used,Free

Used -> 7491362816 ----- Free -> 1096470528

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so your free disc space is 1 GB of 7 GB?
of course this is a bit too less. Probably you already pulled a servercore images which uses around 7 GB.

you need to expand your partition size:
https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848680(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: First I increased the VM operating system disk size. After that I used the Resize-Partition and worked very well. Thank you!