# How to get the remaining amount of storage space in a shared folder

Tags: powershell

I have to create a script which performs some operations in a given folder, but it must include a prior check if there is enough space left before starting the operations. The folder name is an UNC path, e.g. `\\example-server\share1\folder\subfolder\`. How can I get the amount of free space in the folder?

Things that I tried so far:

- I read that I can use `gwmi`, `Get-CimInstance`, `Get-Volume`  and `Get-PSDrive` to get information about a volume, but I don't know how to determine the volume where the folder is stored.
- I tried using [this interesting-looking function, `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35158640/11306603) in my script but sadly it returned with Success=false and an empty value for "Free".

Comment: if you're just wanting to get the size of a folder, this is what i use https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-FolderSize.ps1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following may not be the best solution, but it could work:

```
# Determine all single-letter drive names.
$takenDriveLetters = (Get-PSDrive).Name -like '?'

# Find the first unused drive letter.
# Note: In PowerShell (Core) 7+ you can simplify [char[]] (0x41..0x5a) to
#       'A'..'Z'
$firstUnusedDriveLetter = [char[]] (0x41..0x5a) | 
  where { $_ -notin $takenDriveLetters } | select -first 1

# Temporarily map the target UNC path to a drive letter...
$null = net use ${firstUnusedDriveLetter}: '\\example-server\share1\folder\subfolder' /persistent:no
# ... and obtain the resulting drive's free space ...
$freeSpace = (Get-PSDrive $firstUnusedDriveLetter).Free
# ... and delete the mapping again.
$null = net use ${firstUnusedDriveLetter}: /delete

$freeSpace # output
```

`net use`-mapped drives report their free space, while those established with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive) *as PowerShell-only drives* do not, whereas they do if you create them with `-Persist`<sup>Thanks, [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42).</sup> (which makes the call equivalent to `net use`; from scripts, be sure to also specify `-Scope Global`, due to the bug described in [GitHub issue #15752](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15752)).

I've omitted error handling for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

As per mklement0 example above, `Get-PSDrive` does not return the correct free space value when a quota is applied to the share and/or subfolder within the share. Instead, use the .NET Class System.IO.DriveInfo and the AvailableFreeSpace property:

```
    $freespace = (New-Object -TypeName System.IO.DriveInfo `
                 -ArgumentList $firstUnusedDriveLetter).AvailableFreeSpace
```